# Not able to run the javascript code in VS code

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am facing a problem in VS Code, the problem is earlier I used vs code to run my javascript files but then I started learning ReactJs. I had already installed Node js in my vs code. Now when I try to run my file named "Three.js". I am getting an error at the debug console.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe .\question_three.js
> Debugger attached.
> Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
> throw err;
> ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'd:\javascript\question_three.js'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
> at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }

when I run the react application it works fine. but unable to run a simple javascript file.

Comment: No way to know/guess "what going on" inside your `Three.js`. Follow the basic Three.JS installation guide here (`npm i` the required modules): https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation. VS-code is code editor (The code errors not related to VS-Code).

Comment: Hi , I again tried using Terminal now its running perfectly! . Earlier it showed a strange error! i am getting this error only in debugger console.

Comment: Great, maybe delete this Q (No added value for other users). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can run your file via terminal by first selecting node . For example if you have a file index.js than write node index.js.By default node points to the C:\Users\yourname/. Put your Js file in any of the folder in Users/Yourname/ AnyFolder and than run your js file